# Recovering angles from noisy matrix

Tags: matrices, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

I have a matrix $A$ whose components are given by:

$$A_{ij}=\sin(\theta_i-\theta_j)+N_{ij}$$

where $N_{ij}$ is some noise - you're free to assume $N_{ij}=-N_{ji} \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$ and independent. My goal is to recover the angles $\theta_i$, which are fixed (assuming e.g. $\theta_1=0$ as a reference). I imagine there's some easy way of doing this (some sort of transform), but I don't personally know how, so any insight would be appreciated.

By the way, this is for a personal project.

Comment: What would you do for the same problem with $B_{ij} = \theta_i - \theta_j + N_{ij}$ (i.e. if no sine was there to screw up reality)?

Comment: Note that you cannot reconstruct all the angles, only the relative phases between them. Probably you should fix one of the angles, _e.g._ $\theta_1=0$.

Comment: @Arastas yes I meant to mention that

Comment: @gt6989b Not sure - this isn't my area of expertise

Answer (score 0):

Assume that $i,j$ runs from $1$ to $n$ and assume for a while that there is no noise. Apllying the $\arcsin(\cdot)$ function and recalling $\theta_1=0$ we obtain $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ linear equations in $n-1$ variables, and we can efficiently solve these equations. However, the noise prevents us from a straightforward use of the $\arcsin(\cdot)$ function since it is defined only on $[-1,1]$. We could do some (probably nonlinear) averaging if there were multiple measurements.

**Update**. Suppose that for the fixed value $\theta_i$ we have a set of measurements of $\mu_i=\sin(\theta_i)$ with an additive noise $\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$. Next we apply the projection $\mu_i^*=\min(1,\max(-1, \mu_i))$. Then the expected value of $\theta_i^*=\arcsin(\mu_i^*)$ is $\theta_i$. Moreover, since $\mu_i$ and $\mu_j$ are independednt, the $\theta^*_i$ and $\theta^*_j$ are also independednt. Thus, if we further construct a system of linear equalities and apply the least squares approach, we may expect the unbiased and effective estimate.

Comment: we know for certain that anything above 1 and below -1 is noise so we can squish those numbers to 1 or -1 respectively without problem

Comment: updated answer seems like good approach, will try

Comment: @Shakespeare I did some simulations and (with a lot of measurements) it works for me. Actually, I took $n=5$, $\sigma^2=0.1$ and I have reasonable estimates after $10^4$ measuements.

Answer (score 0):

We should try to focus the problem. There are multiple ways to interpret this problem. What is your model? What are your measurements? What are we trying to solve?

Assume $\mathbf{A}\in\mathbb{C}^{m\times n}$. Assume the entry in row $r$ and column $c$ represents a measurement of $\mathbf{A}_{r,c}$.

Don't try to measure two angles. Just compute the difference 
$$
 \delta = \theta_{1} - \theta_{2}
$$

**1** Column vectors are constant

$$\mathbf{A}_{r,c} = \delta_{c}$$

$\delta_{j}$ is constant for each column $c$. The least squares solution for column $r$ is the *average* of the column entries:
$$
 \delta_{c} = \arcsin \frac{1}{m} \sum_{k=1}^{m} \mathbf{A}_{r,k}
 = \arcsin \frac{1}{m} \sum_{k=1}^{m} \sin \delta_{r,k}
$$

**2 Each matrix element represents a different angle**

There is no solution. In essence you have $\gamma$ and are trying to solve for $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in
$$
 \sin ( \alpha - \beta ) = \gamma
$$

Comment: to start, the problem statement implies the matrix is square. Also, columns are not constant, even without noise?

Comment: @Shakespeare: Let's see if we can get this problem solved. Can you help me understand why the matrix is square? Let's take a $2 \times 2$ example. That is $4$ numbers. Least squares minimizes the difference between measurement and prediction; the difference between inputs and outputs. Would the $4$ matrix elements be the measurements? What are you trying to predict? Consider the case for linear regression. You measure $x$ values and predict $y$ values using a model function $y = m x + b$. What is your model function?

Comment: Well, we have $n$ angles $\theta_1,...,\theta_n$. The resulting matrix is $n \times n$ with $A_{ij}=\sin(\theta_i-\theta_j)+N_{ij}$ as stated. We want to recover the $n$ numbers $\theta_i$ from that matrix. How one might reformulate that into a least squares problem is the issue...